# How do I complete this andWhere Doctrine query?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm assuming this is easy to do with Doctrine, however I have no clue how to do it. I'm sure I am missing something basic.

```
    Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->from('Product p')
                    ->leftJoin('p.Category c' )
                    ->leftJoin('c.Image i')
                    ->where('p.name LIKE ?', '%'.$search.'%'),
```

which works, but I am trying to select the category and tried this, but it didn't work with error "Unknown column parent_id"

```
    Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->from('Product p')
                    ->leftJoin('p.Category c' )
                    ->leftJoin('c.Image i')
                    ->where('p.name LIKE ?', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->andWhere('c.parent_id NOT LIKE ?', '1'),
```

How do I change this Doctrine query to include the andWhere statement?

Comment: _Is_ there a parent_id column? Maybe you should add the schema.

Comment: There is under the category table. I updated the question with the correct working query. I also tried adding ->select('p.*', 'c.*')  which didn't work. This is a project I took over and I am not familiar with Doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess since I don't know your schema.  DQL queries use properties and not database column names.  I suspect that category has a property called parent?

So something like:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('p,c,i')  // Eager load
    ->from('Product p')
    ->leftJoin('p.Category c' )
    ->leftJoin('c.Image i')
    ->leftJoin('c.Parent parentCategory') // Join the parent entity
    ->where('p.name LIKE ?', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->andWhere('parentCategory.id NOT LIKE ?', '1'),
```